Expectation of product of quadratic and linear form for multivariate Gaussian vector
I want to expand the expression $\mathbb{E}[x^T N x x^T L]$ where $x^T L$ and $x^T N x$ will result in scalars, so they can be transposed without losing correctness.
I am trying to use the The Matrix Cookbook page 43, section 8.2.3 formula for the cubic form, but cant understand how to change my expression to be able to use the formula. The formula in the book applies for $\mathbb{E}[xN^Txx^T]$, so I could factor out the $L$ and get to $\mathbb{E}[x^T N x x^T] L$, but my main issue is that the expression in the book requires the $x$ on both sides of $N$ to be not transposed, and my expression is a result of multiplication of a quadratic form and a linear form.
The whole problem in question is about finding the expected value of a cost function $\hat{J}$ with a random vector $x_0$, and I have gotten this far but I am unable to resolve the cubic expression in question
$$
\begin{aligned}
Var[\hat{J}] &= \mathbb{E}[(\hat{J} - \mathbb{E}[\hat{J}])^2] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[(K + x_0^T L + x_0^T N x_0 - (K + \mathbb{E}[x_0^T] L + \mathbb{E}[x_0^T] N \mathbb{E}[x_0] + O))^2] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[(x_0^T L + x_0^T N x_0 - \mathbb{E}[x_0^T] L - \mathbb{E}[x_0^T] N \mathbb{E}[x_0] - O)^2] \\
& \text{let } \mathbb{E}[x_0^T] L + \mathbb{E}[x_0^T] N \mathbb{E}[x_0] + O = W \\
& \text{note: $x_0^T L$ is a scalar, $x_0^T L = L^T x_0$} \\
& \text{note: $\mathbb{E}[x_0^T] N \mathbb{E}[x_0]$, $O$ are deterministic scalars, so $W$ is a deterministic scalar} \\
&= \mathbb{E}[(x_0^T L + x_0^T N x_0 - W)^2] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[x_0^T L x_0^T L + x_0^T L x_0^T N x_0 - x_0^T L W \\
&+ x_0^T N x_0 x_0^T L + x_0^T N x_0 x_0^T N x_0 - x_0^T N x_0 W \\
&- W x_0^T L - W x_0^T N x_0 + W^2] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[x_0^T L L^T x_0 + x_0^T N x_0 x_0^T L - x_0^T L W \\
&+ x_0^T N x_0 x_0^T L + x_0^T N x_0 x_0^T N x_0 - W x_0^T N x_0 \\
&- x_0^T L W - W x_0^T N x_0 + W^2] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[x_0^T L L^T x_0 + 2 x_0^T N x_0 x_0^T L - 2 x_0^T L W + x_0^T N x_0 x_0^T N x_0 - 2 W x_0^T N x_0 + W^2] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[x_0^T] L L^T \mathbb{E}[x_0] + \text{tr}(LL^T \mathbb{C}ov[x_0]) \\
&+ 2\mathbb{E}[x_0^T N x_0 x_0^T] L \\
&- 2 \mathbb{E}[x_0^T] L W \\
&+ 2 \text{tr}(N \mathbb{C}ov[x] N \mathbb{C}ov[x]) + 4 \mathbb{E}[x^T]N\mathbb{C}ov[x]N\mathbb{E}[x] \\
&+ \text{tr}(N\mathbb{C}ov[x])^2 + (\mathbb{E}[x^T]N\mathbb{E}[x])^2 + 2 \text{tr}(N\mathbb{C}ov[x])\mathbb{E}[x^T]N\mathbb{E}[x] \\
&- 2W (\mathbb{E}[x_0^T] N \mathbb{E}[x_0] + \text{tr}(N \mathbb{C}ov[x_0])) \\
& + W^2 \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Please include/cite which part of page 43 you want to use

thanks @ТymaGaidash, I added the section and more context on what my issue stems from

What is the distribution of your $x?$ In general this kind of computation is ruled out by the Leon Isserlis formula: if $X\sim N(0, \Sigma)$ then $$E(X_1X_2X_3X_4)=\Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{34}+\Sigma_{13}\Sigma_{24}+\Sigma_{14}\Sigma_{23}.$$

In case anyone comes across this, I will post the answer here which I have verified with a simple matlab code
Assumptions:

$X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a random vector with mean $\mu = \mathbb{E}[X]$.
The covariance matrix of $X$ is $\Sigma = \text{Cov}(X) = \mathbb{E}[(X - \mu)(X - \mu)^\top]$.
$B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a symmetric matrix.
$A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ is a column vector.

Derivation:

Expression Expansion:
$$
   (X^\top B X) \cdot (X^\top A) = \left( \sum_{i,j} X_i B_{ij} X_j \right) \cdot \left( \sum_{k} X_k A_k \right)
   $$

Combine the Terms:
$$
   (X^\top B X) \cdot (X^\top A) = \sum_{i,j,k} X_i B_{ij} X_j X_k A_k
   $$

Expectation:
$$
   \mathbb{E}[X^\top B X \cdot X^\top A] = \sum_{i,j,k} B_{ij} A_k \mathbb{E}[X_i X_j X_k]
   $$

Third-Order Moments:
The expectation of the product of three normally distributed random variables (assuming $X$ is multivariate normal) can be computed using the fact that for multivariate normal vectors, the third central moments are zero:
$$
   \mathbb{E}[X_i X_j X_k] = \mathbb{E}[(X_i - \mu_i + \mu_i)(X_j - \mu_j + \mu_j)(X_k - \mu_k + \mu_k)]
   $$
Expanding this, we get:
$$
   \begin{aligned}
   \mathbb{E}[X_i X_j X_k] &= \mathbb{E}[(X_i - \mu_i)(X_j - \mu_j)(X_k - \mu_k)] \\
   & \quad + \mu_i \mathbb{E}[(X_j - \mu_j)(X_k - \mu_k)] + \mu_j \mathbb{E}[(X_i - \mu_i)(X_k - \mu_k)] + \mu_k \mathbb{E}[(X_i - \mu_i)(X_j - \mu_j)] \\
   & \quad + \mu_i \mu_j \mu_k
   \end{aligned}
   $$

Evaluate the Expressions:
Since the expectation of the product of zero-mean Gaussian random variables is zero, the first term drops out:
$$
   \mathbb{E}[(X_i - \mu_i)(X_j - \mu_j)(X_k - \mu_k)] = 0
   $$
This simplifies to:
$$
   \begin{aligned}
   \mathbb{E}[X_i X_j X_k] &= \mu_i \Sigma_{jk} + \mu_j \Sigma_{ik} + \mu_k \Sigma_{ij} + \mu_i \mu_j \mu_k
   \end{aligned}
   $$

Substitute Back:
Substituting $\mathbb{E}[X_i X_j X_k] = \mu_i \Sigma_{jk} + \mu_j \Sigma_{ik} + \mu_k \Sigma_{ij} + \mu_i \mu_j \mu_k$ into the original sum:
$$
   \begin{aligned}
   \mathbb{E}[X^\top B X \cdot X^\top A] &= \sum_{i,j,k} B_{ij} A_k \left( \mu_i \Sigma_{jk} + \mu_j \Sigma_{ik} + \mu_k \Sigma_{ij} + \mu_i \mu_j \mu_k \right)
   \end{aligned}
   $$

Simplify:
Breaking this into separate sums:
$$
   \mathbb{E}[X^\top B X \cdot X^\top A] = \sum_{i,j,k} B_{ij} A_k \mu_i \Sigma_{jk} + \sum_{i,j,k} B_{ij} A_k \mu_j \Sigma_{ik} + \sum_{i,j,k} B_{ij} A_k \mu_k \Sigma_{ij} + \sum_{i,j,k} B_{ij} A_k \mu_i \mu_j \mu_k
   $$
Rewriting in matrix form:
$$
   \mathbb{E}[X^\top B X \cdot X^\top A] = \mu^\top B \Sigma A + \mu^\top B \Sigma A + \text{Tr}(B \Sigma) \mu^\top A + (\mu^\top B \mu)(\mu^\top A)
   $$
Combining these:
$$
   \mathbb{E}[X^\top B X \cdot X^\top A] = 2 \mu^\top B \Sigma A + \text{Tr}(B \Sigma) \mu^\top A + (\mu^\top B \mu)(\mu^\top A)
   $$


Code
clc; close all; clear;

% setup
nx = 3;
mu = 1.21;
sigma = 1;
x_mean = repelem(mu, nx)';
x_cov = sigma * eye(nx);
A = randn(nx, 1);
B = randn(nx, nx);
B = B * B'; % make it symmetric
samples = 10000;
x = mvnrnd(x_mean, x_cov, samples)'; % transpose to make it nx by samples
% change the vars to represent reality
x_mean = mean(x, 2);
x_cov = cov(x');

% test cubic
disp("Cubic");
term = 0;
for i = 1:samples
    term = term + (x(:, i)' * B * x(:, i)) * (x(:, i)' * A);
end
st_mean = term/samples;
an_mean = 2 * x_mean' * B * x_cov * A + trace(B * x_cov) * x_mean' * A + (x_mean' * B * x_mean) * (x_mean' * A);
fprintf("Analytic: %f, Statistic: %f\n", an_mean, st_mean);


Assume $N$ is symmetric with nonsingular symmetric square root $N^{1/2}$. Then
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left(X^TNX\ X^TL\right)& = \mathbb{E}\left(X^TNX\ L^TX\right) = \mathbb{E}\left[\text{tr}\left(X^TNX\ L^TX\right) \right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left\lbrace \text{tr}\left[ \left(X^TN^{1/2}\right) \left(N^{1/2}X\right) \left(L^TN^{-1/2}\right)\left( N^{1/2}X \right)\right] \right\rbrace \\
&=\mathbb{E}\left\lbrace \text{tr}\left[  \left(N^{1/2}X\right) \left(L^TN^{-1/2}\right)\left( N^{1/2}X \right)  \left(X^TN^{1/2}\right)\right] \right\rbrace \\
&=\text{tr}\left[\mathbb{E}\left(ub^Tuu^T\right) \right]
\end{align}$$
where $u=N^{1/2}X$, $b=N^{-1/2}L$, and the third line comes from cyclic property of trace. The last expression is in the form of the book referenced.
